# Looping through multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$products = Array ( 

    [0] => Array ( 

        [keyseries_id] => 7 
        [product_id] => 1 
        [name] => Defender standaard sleutel 
        [price] => 6.25 
        [description] => Dit is een test voor de product descriptions 
        [image_id] => 1 
        [imageinfo] => Array ( 

                [filename] => Array ( 

                        [0] => defender_thumb.jpg 
                        [1] => defender_standaard.jpg ) 

                [imagedescription] => Array ( 

                        [0] => dit is een testafbeelding 
                        [1] => Dit is een 2e testafbeelding ) 

                    ) 

            ) 

    [1] => Array ( 

        [keyseries_id] => 7 
        [product_id] => 2 
        [name] => Defender Klapsleutel 
        [price] => 7.00 
        [description] => Dit is de defender klapsleutel.. NU IN DE AANBIEDING!!! 
        [image_id] => 3 
        [imageinfo] => Array ( 

                [filename] => Array ( 

                        [0] => defender_thumb.jpg 
                        [1] => defender_klap.jpg ) 

                [imagedescription] => Array ( 

                        [0] => Defender slot 
                        [1] => Defender klapsleutel ) 

                    ) 

            ) 

    )
```

I want to do a `foreach` loop for every `filename` and `imagedescription`, so I can use the `filename` and `imagedescription` for an `<img>` html tag in my application. Can somebody show me how to do this?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

ANSWER: THANKS TO PHILIPP

Implemented the foreach loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($product['imageinfo']['filename'] as $index => $filename): ?>

                        <?php echo '<img src="http://localhost/sleutelservice/uploads/images/' . $filename . '" alt="' . $product['imageinfo']['imagedescription'][$index].  '">';  ?>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a description for every file:

```
$results = array();
foreach($bigArray as $group){
  foreach($group['imageinfo']['filename'] as $index => $fileName){
    $results[] = array(
      'file' => $filename,
      'description' =>$group['imageinfo']['imagedescription'][$index]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx... This post helped me the most!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply nest two loops in each other to achive this

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $subitem) {
         //do something with subitem
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working... $product['imageinfo']['filename'] gives an array.. So you can't echo that... print_r gives: an array

Comment: Sorry posted my comment probebly on your post... The other post above has been removed... i'm sorry